# Rustlings if2.rs task problem. Control Flow Issue

Tags: rust

I've passed the 1st two but cannot figure out how to get `default_to_baz`

```
test tests::bar_for_fuzz ... ok
test tests::foo_for_fizz ... ok
test tests::default_to_baz ... FAILED
```

My code is

```
pub fn fizz_if_foo(fizzish: &str) -> &str {
    if fizzish == "fizz" {
         "foo"
    } else  {
         "bar"
    }
}
```

The failed test case:

```rust
    #[test]
    fn default_to_baz() {
        assert_eq!(fizz_if_foo("literally anything"), "baz")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed this test `default_to_baz`, I just guess you are solving the rustlings exercises, the test body is

```rust
    #[test]
    fn default_to_baz() {
        assert_eq!(fizz_if_foo("literally anything"), "baz")
    }
```

This is used to test when the input string does not equal to "fizz" or `fuzz`, so the solution is simple, just add a `else` branch:

```rust
pub fn fizz_if_foo(fizzish: &str) -> &str {
    if fizzish == "fizz" {
        "foo"
    } else if fizzish == "fuzz" {
        "bar"
    } else {
        "baz"
    }
}
```

Or we can use `match`, it's an alternative way:

```rust
pub fn fizz_if_foo(fizzish: &str) -> &str {
    match fizzish {
        "fizz" => "foo",
        "fuzz" => "bar",
        _ => "baz",
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi yes i am working through. I am completely fresh on Rust and this helps me alot... It got a little more complicated for me here. Thanks for your swift and detailed response mate.

Comment: @Highlander It's recommended to read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions here, then you will ask good questions that won't be closed by others.